# Cannot concatenate object when adding to a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to add a sentence as well as a coin(like a label in this case I guess) to a DataFrame. Although I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\gjohn\Documents\code\machineLearning\trading_bot\filter.py", line 132, in <module>
        df = df.append({'coin': coin, 'review': sentence}, ignore_index=True)
      File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2877, in append
        return concat(
      File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 294, in concat
        op = _Concatenator(
      File "C:\Users\gjohn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 384, in __init__
        raise TypeError(msg)
 TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Here is the code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\gjohn\\Documents\\code\\machineLearning\\trading_bot\\testreviews.csv')
df = data['review'] # Create a dataframe of the reviews.
classes = data['class'] # Create a dataframe of the classes.
for sentence in sentences:
    coin = find_coin(common_words, sentence)
    if len(sentence) > 0 and coin != None:
        df = df.append({'coin': coin, 'review': sentence}, ignore_index=True)
```

I can't find how to fix this and I really need help, it would be great if you could help me out. Thanks!

Also sorry for the messy code :D

Comment: `data['review']` is a Series, not a DataFrame

Comment: Oh ok. how to can I make it a DataFrame?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(data['review'])` will make a DataFrame, but by appending like that, you will have null values in `coin` column for existing rows. Maybe you want to append to the `data` not `df`

Comment: Is there a way to just replace each row of the DataFrame? Data has extra things I still need but don't want to worry about when going through the reviews.  I basically go through each review, filter out the symbols and stopwords, and then put them back into the DataFrame.

Comment: I can not connect this idea with the code in the question. Anyway, for doing this, you can iterate on the DataFrame like: `for ind, row in data.iterrows()` and then update each review like this: `row["review"] = process(row["review"])`

Comment: I tried this:  
`for ind, row in data.iterrows():          row['review'] = sentence          row['coin'] = sentence_coin `
But now it is not changing the DataFrame at all

Answer (score 0):

What is the `sentence` you use to construct the dictionary?

Perhaps you should check if the dictionary is constructed correctly?

Comment: Sentence is just a string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).